# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n + 4^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large n]{3^n + 4^n}.$$
Sorry, I'm not really sure how to find this limit. Can someone share a clever trick for this?

Comment: $$ \Big[ 3^{n} + 4^{n} \Big]^{\frac{1}{n}} = 4 \Big[ 1+\Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)^{n} \Big]^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

Comment: Take $y=(3^n+4^n)^{1/n}$ and calculate the limit for $\ln(y)$ and then exponentiate the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have

$$3^n=_\infty o(4^n)$$
so
$$\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}\sim_\infty\sqrt[n]{4^n}=4$$

Comment: Nice, the $o$ notation means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}3^n/4^n = 0$, right? Can you please elaborate on how this implies that $\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}\sim_\infty\sqrt[n]{4^n}=4$?

Comment: This is exactly the same as @N.S. answer but without doing calculus: we say that $3^n$ is negligible compared to $4^n$ so it can be omitted.

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $$3^n+4^n =4^n \left( 1+ (\frac{3}{4})^n\right)$$

And $1+ (\frac{3}{4})^n \to 1$

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n + 4^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n \left ( \left (\frac{3}{4} \right )^n+1 \right )}=4 \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n] {\left (\frac{3}{4} \right )^n+1 }=4 \cdot 1=4 $$

Answer (score 3):

Using inequalities

$$4=\sqrt[n]{4^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{4^n+4^n} = \sqrt[n]{2}\cdot 4$$

so

$$4\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2}\cdot 4 = 4$$

therefore

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}=4$$